# How to add crystal report in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

This is the first time I am using crystal report but I do not want to use wizard so I tried this code

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Linq
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared

Public Class view_fir_rpt_frm
Dim cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CRMSconn").ConnectionString)
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim cmd As SqlCommand


Private Sub view_fir_rpt_frm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    cn.Open()
    da = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from fir", cn)
    da.Fill(ds, "fir")
     MsgBox(ds.Tables("fir").Rows.Count)
    cn.Close()
    Dim cr As New CrystalReport1
    "cr.SetDataSource(ds.tables("fir"))"
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr
    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()

End Sub
End Class
```

I am getting error in the quoted line that the report has no table. So can anyone suggest me what change should I do in the code?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `cr.SetDataSource(ds.tables("fir"))` to `cr.SetDataSource(ds)` and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: hey i got that .setdatasource takes 2 parameters